# Spring Boot request body semi-required fields

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

In our application user can write a message based on user id or screen name.

```
class Message {
    public final Long userId;
    public final String screenName;
    public final String text;

    @JsonCreator
    public Message(@JsonProperty(value = "user_id", required = ???) Long userId,
                   @JsonProperty(value = "screen_name", required = ???) String screenName,
                   @JsonProperty(value = "text", required = true) String text) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.screenName = screenName;
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Fields userId and screenName can't be optional at same time, one should be provided.

How in Spring Boot to mark that they are semi-required?

Comment: What did you mean by semi required ! At least one of them should be present ?

Comment: yes, one of them should be present

Comment: are you using a json schema to validate your json? Json schema provides (oneOf; anyOf, ...) for such use cases.

Comment: If you're using spring version higher or equal to 4.1 and also java8 you can use the Optional class .. and simply test on userId and screenName before beginning your business

Answer (score 0):

This seems like more of a validation concern rather than deserialization.

Create a Validator then put @Valid within the @RequestMapping on the controller.

See more here:
[Spring REST Validation Example](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-31-valid-requestbody)

Comment: Article from 2012. Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

**From jenkov tutorials:**

> @JsonValue
>
> The Jackson annotation @JsonValue tells Jackson that Jackson should
>   not attempt to serialize the object itself, but rather call a method
>   on the object which serializes the object to a JSON string. Note that
>   Jackson will escape any quotation marks inside the String returned by
>   the custom serialization, so you cannot return e.g. a full JSON
>   object. For that you should use @JsonRawValue instead (see previous
>   section).
>
> The @JsonValue annotation is added to the method that Jackson is to
>   call to serialize the object into a JSON string. Here is an example
>   showing how to use the @JsonValue annotation:

```
public class PersonValue {

    public long   personId = 0;
    public String name = null;

    @JsonValue
    public String toJson(){
        return this.personId + "," + this.name;
    }

}
```

> The output you would get from asking Jackson to serialize a
>   PersonValue object is this:

```
"0,null"
```

**So you can use `@JsonValue` and put your code either to ignore or not from some fields when you try to convert into JSON**

```
@JsonValue
public String toJson(){
    //ignore fields or include them here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just throw an IllegalArgumentException.  The best case would be to deserialize, then run through a validator though so you separate the concerns of serialization, and domain validation.

```
class Message {
    public final Long userId;
    public final String screenName;
    public final String text;

    @JsonCreator
    public Message(@JsonProperty(value = "user_id", required = false) Long userId,
                   @JsonProperty(value = "screen_name", required = false) String screenName,
                   @JsonProperty(value = "text", required = true) String text) {
        if(userId == null && screenName == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("userId or screenName must be provided.");
        }
        this.userId = userId;
        this.screenName = screenName;
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```